Logic Apps copy action gives: The managed identity used with this operation no longer exists. To continue, set up an identity or change the connection
I have a simple flow in Logic Apps - it runs some KQL against Sentinel, creates a CSV from the results and attaches the CSV to an email and sends it.
I want to run 2 KQL queries, and attach 2 CSVs to the email - so I copy the "Run Query and List Results" action, and paste it when adding a new action - however the new (copied) action shows the error:


The Subscription, Resource Group, Resource Type and Resource Name are all identical.
Does anyone have any idea what is wrong, and how I can get this flow to run two KQL queries?
Thanks for any help,
Mark

managed identity is needed here to get the permission the run KQL

Make sure that the managed identity selected in your Run query and list results-copy action is correct:

You can also check its ID in the Code View:

This managed identity should have a proper role assigned to access your logs, e.g. in my environment it looks like this:

